# Visual Studio Xamarin Apple Accounts options can't download provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, provisioning-profile

In Visual Studio 2017, opening Tools -> Options then Xamarin -> Apple Accounts then selecting an individual and clicking "View Details" opens a dialog that tries to load Certificates and Provisioning Profiles from my Apple Id account, but after 30 seconds or so times out with an error dialog "There was an error while downloading your provisioning profiles: Your session has expired. Please log in." How do I "log in", or make it be able to download my provisioning profiles?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove and then re-Add your Apple ID in the "Apple IDs" list, then select the individual and click "View Details..." again, upon which the Certificates and Provisioning Profiles are successfully downloaded.

(Remove/Add and re-entering login info kind of defeats the purpose of storing your Apple ID and password...but whatever.)